# A question about counter-term in Lagrangian of interacting field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization

In book Quantum Field Theory, written by Srednicki. There is a Lagrangian defined in section 9:
$$
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{2}Z_\varphi\partial^\mu\varphi\partial_\mu\varphi-\frac{1}{2}Z_mm^2\varphi^2+\frac{1}{3!}Z_gg\varphi^3+Y\varphi
$$
Then we will see the average of field in vaccum $\langle{0}|\varphi(x)|0\rangle$ is not vanished due to the "tadpole" diagrams (see eq(9.19)), unless we let $Y$ diverges (or becomes a very large quantity which depends on ultraviolet cut off, see eq(9.23)).

**My question is,** $Y\varphi$ is a term similar to "source term $J\varphi$", which is expected to be $0$ in vacuum (indeed, this book set $J=0$ before this section).  Even the momentum cut off is finite, a non-zero $Y$ will produce a "wrong" equation of motion by Lagrangian, because actually we have no "source" at all.

How should I understand this?

Comment: An aside: $Y\phi$ doesn't vanish in the vacuum $|0\rangle$ of a spontaneously broken theory with a nonzero VEV.

Comment: I know before SSB，this term vanished and not observable. But it does add $Y$ in equation of motion （K-G equation）.

Answer (score 2):

> ... because actually we have no "source" at all.

Actually, the "tadpole" diagram shows you how you *do* have a "quantum-fluctuation source": imagine a $\phi$ particle-antiparticle pair created from the vacuum. Then one of those splits into two with $\phi^3$ vertex. And then two of the resulting three annihilate.

Comment: I was taught that "source" $J\varphi$ is something like a point with one leg in the diagram...I am not sure what do you mean

Comment: @bacon Tadpole diagram looks similar, isn't it? It is a loop with a leg from it, right? So now this loop serves as a source.

Comment: I get your point，but a modified Largrangian gives a strange equation of motion (with Y), how should I explain this?

Comment: @bacon http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17592/guessing-what-a-simple-partial-differential-equation-is-describing-physically/17595#17595

Comment: I mean, $(\partial^2-m^2)\varphi=Y$ is weird.

Comment: @bacon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation#Klein.E2.80.93Gordon_equation_in_a_potential